# CSS load failed in REACT

Tags: webpack, require

I have a problem when loading CSS in react.

My source code is like this.

```
const Index = ({ .... }) => {
...
   useEffect(() => {
   ...
      console.log('data : ', data);
      // require('#a/b/c/d/e.css');
      require(data.src);
```

When I load the css using string url, It works properly.
But when I load the css as variable, it can not work.

Error log is like this.

```
Cannot find module '#a/b/c/d/e.css'
webpackEmptyContext
webpack:~ sync:2
```

and Console.log is like this.

```
data :  
{key: "9999", src: "#a/b/c/d/e.css"}
key: "9999"
src: "#a/b/c/d/e.css"
```

I want to use url as variable. Is there any solution about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack has no way of knowing what the value of the variable is, so it cannot compile the file.

You should define the path clearly or webpack will throw errors.

Comment: Thanks. Based on your comment, I found a QnA about web pack.
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6680
Have a good day :-)